# How can I replace the href for an existing canonical tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace the existing canonical tag on this page https://www.example.com/tours.htm with https://www.example.com/amp/tours.html. I tried the following below but it didn't work. Is there a way to replace canonical tag dynamically on a page?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

$('link[rel="canonical"]').attr('href', 'https://www.example.com/amp/tours.html');


    }
</script>
```

Comment: This smells of spam. Use mock/generic urls instead.

Comment: Amit, I will edit my URLs but just so you and everyone knows - this is not a scam! I tried using in prior questions http://tinyurl.com/ but StackOverflow didn't allow this. So please take your attitude elsewhere.

Comment: @Amit is right.  Your question is **how** to do it, it doesn't have to be using your URLs - the **how** will work for any.

Comment: Good to know but never had problem posting URLs here before. I though the questions should be as detailed as possible including what I did to fix the issue and where the issue occurs. Or did something change in the meantime?. As I said I tried using tinyurl.com but it didn't work.

Comment: you have syntax error. You miss `);` before `</script>`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('link[href="https://www.example.com/tours.html"]').attr('href','https://www.example.com/amp/tours.html');
```

Include the href in the selector to avoid changing all your rel="canonical" links.

Comment: Thanks user2182349. I trued this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry about that - I changed **rel** to **href** in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

This will dynamically pull in the page URL and replace the canonical link tag with the current page URL.

`var pageURL = $(location).attr("href"); 
$('link[rel="canonical"]').attr('href', pageURL);`